# How to avoid update checks with CMake FetchContent?

Tags: c++, cmake, catch2

all.

I decided to use the new cmake macro to download external dependencies.
I took the sample code from the documentation for the Catch2 library.

```
include(FetchContent)

FetchContent_Declare(
    Catch2
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2.git
    GIT_TAG        v2.13.4
)
FetchContent_GetProperties(Catch2)
if(NOT Catch2_POPULATED)
    FetchContent_Populate(Catch2)
    add_subdirectory(${catch2_SOURCE_DIR} ${catch2_BINARY_DIR})
endif()
```

The solution works great, except for the ability to restart the cmake when I am offline (no wifi and mobile network only me and my laptop).
I get the following error:

```
[0/7] Performing update step for 'catch2-populate'
fatal: «https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2.git/» недоступно: Could not resolve host: github.com
CMake Error at /Users/evgeny.proydakov/repository/ihft/build/_deps/catch2-subbuild/catch2-populate-prefix/tmp/catch2-populate-gitupdate.cmake:97 (execute_process):
  execute_process failed command indexes:

    1: "Child return code: 128"

FAILED: catch2-populate-prefix/src/catch2-populate-stamp/catch2-populate-update 
cd /Users/evgeny.proydakov/repository/ihft/build/_deps/catch2-src && /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.20.1/bin/cmake -P /Users/evgeny.proydakov/repository/ihft/build/_deps/catch2-subbuild/catch2-populate-prefix/tmp/catch2-populate-gitupdate.cmake
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.20.1/share/cmake/Modules/FetchContent.cmake:1012 (message):
  Build step for catch2 failed: 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.20.1/share/cmake/Modules/FetchContent.cmake:1141:EVAL:2 (__FetchContent_directPopulate)
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.20.1/share/cmake/Modules/FetchContent.cmake:1141 (cmake_language)
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.20.1/share/cmake/Modules/FetchContent.cmake:1184 (FetchContent_Populate)
  .cmake/icmake.cmake:46 (FetchContent_MakeAvailable)
  CMakeLists.txt:10 (include)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Is it possible to download dependency one time, check revision and don't try to connect each time to remote server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html#command:fetchcontent_populate) for `FetchContent_Populate` says you can get exactly what you want with the `FETCHCONTENT_UPDATES_DISCONNECTED` cache variable:

> **`FETCHCONTENT_UPDATES_DISCONNECTED`**
>
> ... This ... disables the
> update stage. Therefore, if content has not been downloaded
> previously, it will still be downloaded when this option is enabled.
> This can speed up the configure stage... It is `OFF` by default.

So set this one to `ON` globally, or for Catch2 only, set the variable `FETCHCONTENT_UPDATES_DISCONNECTED_Catch2` to `ON`.